# Is TypedActor alternative to executing blocking call in regular actor?

Tags: akka

I have a scenario where an Actor sends data in a blocking call when it receives a message. This can become a problem in that sometimes the send can block for an excessively long time for reasons beyond my control. This then can cause the Actor's message box to fill up with pending messages during this blockage which causes my app to run out of memory. So I need a way to turn the data send into an asynchronous call

One solution I am looking at is to use a TypedActor fire and forget approach for the send which should avoid the message queue filling up in the Actor. But my question is with this approach would I just be kicking the can down the road in that the typed actor would now just inherit the problem and have its message queue filling up? Below is a simplified version of a possible implementation:

```
trait AsyncPipe[D] {        
    def send(data: D): Unit
}

class AsyncPipeImpl[D](fire: D => Unit) extends AsyncPipe[D] {  
    def send(data: D): Unit = fire(data)
}

class BlockingPipe {
    def send(str: String) = { 
        // Does a blocking send
    }
}

class MyActor extends Actor {

    val bp = new BlockingPipe

    val ap: AsyncPipe[String] = TypedActor(context.system).typedActorOf(
            TypedProps(classOf[AsyncPipe[String]], new AsyncPipeImpl(bp.send)))

    def receive = {
        case msg: String =>
            ap.send(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could certainly could wrap that blocking call with a `Future` that executes on a different execution context (one for blocking ops maybe) from the main actor system, but you will eventually flood that context too.  If these calls are indeed always long running and you have a constant stream of requests to perform them you are going to need to put some thought into capping them so only so many queued ones are allowed before you start rejecting requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all  you need  to decide if you want to reject new incoming messages or timeout pending requests.

Regardless of the above, I will suggest to use [Typed Router Pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed-actors.html#Typed_Router_pattern)  to hide logic responsible for having **multiple requests handlers**.

If you want to reject incoming messages you should use appropriate [bounded mailbox config](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html).

If you want to timeout request you should use `Future` inside `TypedActor` with specified timeout.

Of course you can combine this two strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking probably shouldn't be done in an actor at all (it only makes sense if you need some kind of complex access to mutable resources *while* doing the blocking call, IMO) - can you solve the problem with a simple `Future`, maybe with its own thread pool (execution context)?

Anywhere you queue you're risking filling it up (akka doesn't have good backpressure support IME, though @hicolour has offered some options). It's better to rearrange things so your actor pulls work rather than having it pushed to it (or possibly a mutual-pulling style like the iteratee pattern), so that you don't have to queue.